# MySQL updating data for only one column when run simultaneously from two different applications to update 2 columns

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have a query in a stored procedure which goes something like the following:

```
 update a,b
 set col1=0, col2='Y'
 where a.id=b.id;
```

Now when we run this stored procedure through our standalone script(job1), it is able to update both columns for all rows that match the condition.

But when we try to run the same script simultaneously with another job(job2) that updates the col1 from table a, our update script(stored proc) only updates the 2nd column i.e. col2 and col1 is  updated to some other value by job2.

Does this mean that there is a column-level lock that is getting acquired by job2 which is preventing the job1 to update col1 and only let it update col2? How can this be handled in MySQL Innodb?

Comment: There are no column level locks. Most probably you just f...ed something up. If you did or not, in both cases there's not nearly enough information to be able to help.

Comment: @fancyPants How is only column2 getting updated? What more information do you need?